# Can a cell in ui-grid be rendered in two rows if content is too large?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, css, angular-ui-grid

Can angularjs grid be configured such that if content fits it just shows one row, but if content is big it expands to two rows maximum?

Comment: Short answer is yes. What have you tried? Also, which grid module of angular are you using? please edit your question with more details

Comment: .ui-grid-cell-contents {
     height: 40px;
     white-space: normal;
     -ms-text-overflow: clip;
     -o-text-overflow: clip;
     text-overflow: clip;
     overflow: visible;
}

Comment: .ui-grid-cell {
    height: 50px !important;
}
Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: no i am looking for something more dynamic, like if the content inside cell can fit in one row, than adjust height accordingly, and if content is large, than adjust height to accomodate two rows instead of showing ellipses at the end